# Must my project know the concrete type of a class that I'm about do deserialize?

Tags: java, serialization, classpath

I had as a plan defining an interface `I` that would be shared by a lot of objects that were going to be serialized by a server of mine to a client. The idea would be that the client would only know the interface and never have to bother about knowing any of the concrete implementations of `I`.

The problem seems to be that that doesn' seem to be possible, as when deserializing, Java needs to find the class I'm about to deserialize in its classpath.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

yes, the client will need the concrete implementations in its classpath.  generally it is just easiest to include all the implementations in the client jars.  in some extreme situations, it may make sense to make the implementations loadable on-the-fly, in which case you could use the remote classloading feature of rmi (note, this is generally very tricky to setup and not worth the effort).

Answer (score 1):

Where would the client's VM get the byte code for the implementations?  Unless you want to start sending the concrete implementation classes across the wire, this approach just isn't going to work.  The client's going to need the concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This very much comes down to what the class has to implement in the way of functionality.

If your class is nothing more than a bean containing data, then your client code could look to  ASM and other techniques of dynamic run time byte code manipulation. A good example I used recently was Jackson's Mr Bean. It only need a very simple interface to create whole beans on the fly.

If you need to have actual functionality in your class and this functionality is not in the client, then I would expect that you would need to look into serialising a class, sending it down the wire and then probably some sort of custom class loader which can load a class from the deserialised data.